# ViewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter nested scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I've setup my activity layout using `ViewPager2`, `BottomNavigationView` and Fragments. In my First fragment in `ViewPager2` contains a `ImageSlider`.

When I scroll the ImageSlider the entire fragment (in `ViewPager2`) scrolls to 2nd Fragment. Why is this happening ?.

Then I changed to Normal `ViewPager` instead of `ViewPager2`  and `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStateAdapter`, the it works perfectly, unfortunately `FragmentPagerAdapter` is deprecated.?

**Layout**

```
 <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Activity**

```
val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this)
viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
const val FRAGMENT_COUNT = 4;

class ViewPagerAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(activity){

override fun getItemCount() = FRAGMENT_COUNT

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when(position) {
        0 -> HomeFragment()
        1 -> DepartmentFragment()
        2 -> ConnectFragment()
        3 -> SocialFragment()
        else -> HomeFragment()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try to disable nested scrolling of the internal `RecyclerView` of the `ViewPager2`.. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749500/how-to-enable-dragging-on-viewpager2-inside-bottomsheetdialogfragment/67865776#67865776) could help in that

Answer (score 2):

Intercepting ViewPager2 touch listener is not possible as we cannot extend it like we do in the ViewPager, due to this viewpager don't allow any nested view to scroll. So you need to write a wrapper view around the viewpager2 which will handle this touch interceptor and allow other views to receive scrolling.

Checkout [NestedTabSroller](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt) class from the Google ViewPager2 sample. This class will solve your problem