# How to enable dragging on ViewPager2 inside BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

There's a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and working good vertically dragging states on fragment layout and opening `STATE_EXPANDED` mode. There's a `recyclerview` inside it and dragging vertically works on the bottom sheet but it doesn't work on `recyclerview` because of scrolling event. How the bottom sheet dragging event to work instead of scroll event on `recyclerview` when reached top of list and still scrolling up for collapse the bottom sheet?

BottomSheetDialogFragment hierarchy:

```
FragmentRootLinearLayout -> ...BottomLinearLayout... -> ViewPager2 -> RecyclerView
```

BottomSheetDialogFragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/BookInfoFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tool_sheet_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_linear_layout"
        style="@style/ThemeSettingsRowContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_rounded_corner_bg2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/book_loading_tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/book_loading_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**:
The issue is on ViewPager2, when I change it to ViewPager dragging is working good on it. Same issue: [BottomSheet + ViewPager2 drag to hide not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915600/bottomsheet-viewpager2-drag-to-hide-not-works)

Comment: Add your xml code @ATES

Comment: it's like that.

Comment: so when you reach top of list ,you are trying to drag the bottom sheet down but it's not collapsing instead recycler view still scrolling ? Am i Correct?@ATES

Comment: yes you're right, and recyclerview onScrollEvent not handling because of scroll finished from top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that we need to disable the nested scrolling on the `ViewPager2`, but the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` doesn't work because `ViewPager2` is functioning internally using `RecyclerView` which has the effect of the nested scrolling.

So, you need to disable the nested scrolling of the `ViewPager` `RecyclerView`.

The main issue is that the `RecyclerView` of `ViewPager2`  is not accessible by default.

> **Update Feb.2022**
>
> Adding a better way to access the `RecyclerView` of the `ViewPager2` instead of using reflections:

Kotlin:

```
viewPager2.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
    (it as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
```

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < viewPager2.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = mViewPager.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof RecyclerView)
        ((RecyclerView) child).setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

This should work, but if still facing issues, then try to disable the over scroll mode of the `RecyclerView`:

```
// Kotlin
recyclerView?.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER // Optional
// Java
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER); // Optional
```

Preview:

[image]

---

With Reflections
----

You can access it using [java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

And this requires to know the name field of the `RecyclerView` which can be found in the [`ViewPager2`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-collection-release/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java) definition class which is `mRecyclerView`

Combining that together in a helper function:

```
public static RecyclerView getRecyclerView(ViewPager2 viewPager) {
    try {
        Field field = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (RecyclerView) field.get(viewPager);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can disable the nested scrolling as follows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getRecyclerView(viewPager);
if (recyclerView != null)
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

```
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

**For Kotlin users:**

Extension function:

```
fun ViewPager2.getRecyclerView(): RecyclerView? {
    try {
        val field = ViewPager2::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView")
        field.isAccessible = true
        return field.get(this) as RecyclerView
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

And usage:

```
val recyclerView = viewPager.getRecyclerView()
recyclerView?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
recyclerView?.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER // Optional
```

Comment: thanks, works but why scroll up don't working on recyclerview?

Comment: @ATES Do you mean the RecyclerView of the `ViewPager2` or do you have another `RecyclerView` in the BottomSheet?

Comment: I mean RC on ViewPager2, scrolling to down works but to up not working, dragging bottomsheet instead of scrolling to up.

Comment: when I scroll to up right after scroll to down work good but if i scroll to up after waiting a bit (when finished the scroll) it doesn't work :)

Comment: @ATES I have tired that with `ViewPager1` and that seems the default behavior in both ViewPager 1, 2..  hopefully I got you well.. I'm afraid that I didn't get you can you show some gif so that I can understand more

Comment: @ATES Thanks for sharing it.. I think this is not due to the `ViewPager2` behavior, as depicted in gif, there is a some scrollable view in the page of the `ViewPager` something like `ScrollView` or `RecyclerView`, which is causing this behavior.. Not sure if disabling its nested scrolling will solve it or not but give it a try. But I think this scroll is good to allow users to scroll up again if they wish instead of dragging the bottom sheet at once.

Comment: There'are only a RecyclerView insede ConstraintLayout in the frame xml, no any listener, current event or other effectual things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233517/discussion-between-zain-and-ates).

Comment: As last update: RecyclerView inside the veiwpager2 should setNestedScrollingEnabled() to be false but setNestedScrollingEnabled() should be true when creating RecyclerView firstly, so work good.

Answer (score 0):

If you use  STATE_EXPANDED  mode is default mode and hideable property is true ,you can not drag it down.

So set  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED  is default mode and set hideable ,PeakHight property.

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/BookInfoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        
        app:behavior_peekHeight="500dp"
         app:behavior_hideable="false"

        android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

[image]

Comment: Not worked for me, TabLayout and all of areas is draggable except ViewPager2, all of problem is on it. I've deleted the recyclerview and it's empty but still not draggable. I couldn't find any property for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915600/bottomsheet-viewpager2-drag-to-hide-not-works

Comment: When I changed the viewpager2 to viewpager works good.